# Error Veil Evasion

Tags: linux

PyInstaller v3.2 is already installed... Skipping...????

```
[*] Installing Python's PyInstaller


 [*] PyInstaller v3.2 is already installed... Skipping...

Reading profile /etc/firejail/wine.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Warning: noroot option is not available
Parent pid 7361, child pid 7362
The new log directory is /proc/7362/root/var/log
Child process initialized in 63.71 ms
000d:err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/root/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-py.desktop"
000d:err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/root/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-pyc.desktop"
000d:err:menubuilder:write_freedesktop_association_entry error writing association file "/root/.local/share/applications/wine-extension-pyw.desktop"
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is it not already installed?

Comment: Please clarify what your question is, what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: My problem is the last three lines I searched and found no solution The installation starts normally but stops and does not complete the installation Do i have to wait a long time to finish ?? I guess the problem is (wine-extension)
@MaxvonHippel

Comment: Please put that information in the question not in a comment.

Comment: Abdulla, you should read our [documentation on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you would like for someone to answer your question.